# Python libraries for clustering decimals

Tags: python, nlp, data-analysis, machine-learning

I have a collection of decimals, with each a value between 0.0 and 1.0.

I would like to "cluster" them by value on two dimensions, so that decimals with near values are grouped together, yet spaced enough so that the graph is visually pleasing.

What libraries in Python can I consider to do this?

Requirements:

- speed over accuracy
- preferably free

Comment: I'm putting this on hold because it's asking for a recommendation on where to start on a problem, not for a piece of software. If you can [edit] your question to ask for a piece of software matching specific requirements, we can reopen it.

Comment: I made the question on-topic, by modifying it a lot.

Comment: What are your two dimensions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the module [sklearn.cluster](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) from the Python library [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org) (free and open-source).

[image]

E.g. if you want to use the k-means algorithm:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans_model = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=1).fit(X)
labels = kmeans_model.labels_
metrics.silhouette_score(X, labels, metric='euclidean')
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using Spectral Clustering and it seems to serve the purpose very well.